# Using SURF how to give result by saying this is the matching image?

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I'm doing a project to recognize the value of currency note and i should return the value.I used **SURF algorithm** to detect the value.There are several templates of currency values and i match those templates with currency images which captured from mobile camera..

by using SURF i could matching the value and if value matched its draw a rectangle around the vale.if the value is not matching not draw the rectangle....

***Problem is how i return the matching value..It's enough to show the value on command prompt.***Please help me.
thank you very much..

Answer (score 4):

After you call [matchTemplate](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate) you will get a matrix result

```
void matchTemplate(InputArray image, InputArray temp, OutputArray result, int method)
```

Result is a matrix which maps the comparison results. Method could be CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED.

You can find the bets matches by using the function [minMaxLoc](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc)().

You can consider the matching value as a probability that you find a particular "currency value". You can also set a threshold for the matching value, that way if you are not deteccting any of the patterns you know, you should get matching outputs below that threshold.